# Multiple Sort Lists of Strings

Tags: python, sorting, collections

I have a list of a person's "interests" that looks like:

```
[u'technology and computing', u'software', u'shareware and freeware']
[u'art and entertainment', u'shows and events', u'festival']
[u'art and entertainment', u'shows and events', u'circus']
[u'technology and computing', u'computer certification']
[u'news']
[u'religion and spirituality', u'islam']
```

These are taxonomies output from an NLP API, and I am trying to run further analyses where I draw some higher level conclusions about what sorts of things someone is interested in, based on things like how often `item[0]=='art and entertainment'` appears, and if so, what specific types of arts and entertainment someone is interested in (e.g. `if item[0]=='art and entertainment': return item[:-1]`

Anyway, I could use some guidance on a good approach. My first thought was to calculate the `max(len())` of an item in the list (in my case 5), and then

```
for item in list: 
    append((max(len()) - len(item))*'null,')
```

in order to make sure they all have the same number of "columns", then convert it all to a named tuple and do a multi-sort on that. Seems like an annoying process. Is there a simpler (yet readable) way to handle this?

I've thought about using NLTK or something but that seems like just a big a pain to setup, even if it would make the analysis easier once I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.izip_longet` to zip your lists so you will have a list contain the columns of your main list that the missing elements have been replaced with `None`:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> a=[[u'technology and computing', u'software', u'shareware and freeware'],
... [u'art and entertainment', u'shows and events', u'festival'],
... [u'art and entertainment', u'shows and events', u'circus'],
... [u'technology and computing', u'computer certification'],
... [u'news'],
... [u'religion and spirituality', u'islam']]

>>> list(izip_longest(*a))
[(u'technology and computing', u'art and entertainment', u'art and entertainment', u'technology and computing', u'news', u'religion and spirituality'), (u'software', u'shows and events', u'shows and events', u'computer certification', None, u'islam'), (u'shareware and freeware', u'festival', u'circus', None, None, None)]
```

Then you can do any operation on your columns that you want!

But if you just want to add `None` to your incomplete list you can use `itertools.repeat` :

```
>>> max_len=max(map(len,a))
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> [i+list(repeat(None,max_len-len(i))) for i in a]
[[u'technology and computing', u'software', u'shareware and freeware'], [u'art and entertainment', u'shows and events', u'festival'], [u'art and entertainment', u'shows and events', u'circus'], [u'technology and computing', u'computer certification', None], [u'news', None, None], [u'religion and spirituality', u'islam', None]]
```

Comment: This appears to break the relationship between between the elements of the sub-list, though. That 'shows and events' is in essence a child of the 'art and entertainment' node is something i need to preserve....which makes me think maybe I should do the analysis with trees.